# Hiding DGV columns according to the data of another column

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2012

I have a modified DataGridView (done with VB.NET) which data (from a SQL Server 2012 database) displays well. However, based on the values of the cells in a preexistent column in the dgv, I want to hide the new two columns I created.

I have the following code added in my files, but it give me the "waiting for an identifier". I wanted to select cells to compare:

```
        If Me.movtype.ToString != "CRF" Or Me.movtype.ToString != "CRFE" Or Me.movtype.ToString != "CRV" Or
            Me.movtype.ToString != "CRVE" Or Me.movtype.ToString != "VRF" Or Me.movtype.ToString != "VRFE" Or 
            Me.movtype.ToString != "VRV" Or Me.movtype.ToString != "VRVE" Or Then

        Me.NewCol1.Visible = False
        Me.NewCol2.Visible = False
End if
```

My idea is, if movtype cells are different to the values posted above, the NewCol1 and NewCol2 must be hidden in the DGV. If these strings are equal, the columns must be visible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: vb.net uses <>, c# uses !=  You also have a hanging "or" at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused with the operators. I changed those != to <> and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

@LarsTech was correct. I used the wrong operator and I had an error in my code.